# Getting the url of the reference fields using Graph QL

Tags: graphql, xm-cloud

I want to expose my Sitecore data to frontend using GraphQL edge queries. How do I get the url of the items selected in the multilist field? I tried using url keyword but getting the below error (see screenshot)
[image]

How can we achieve the same? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

To get the URL of selected item in the multilist (reference filed) you can build up a query like below.

Here I'm using the default jss site with running a local docker/graphql instance.

```
query GetItemByItemID($itemId: String!){
  item(path:$itemId){
    ... on StyleguideFieldUsageContentList{
    name
    path
    sharedContentList{
      targetItems{
         ... on StyleguideContentListItemTemplate{
          url
          displayName
          textField{
            value
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Query Variables:**
{"itemId":"{4394DB92-9283-5AC6-9E8C-5C60DC32A140}"}

[image]
[image]

GraphQL requires that you construct your queries in a way that only returns concrete data. Each field has to ultimately resolve to one or more scalars. That means you cannot just request a field that resolves to a type without also indicating which fields of that type you want to get back.

That's what the error message you received is telling you. you requested an `ItemUrl!`, but you didn't tell GraphQL at least one field to get back from that type.

@serhii has already given more details to fix it.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

The error message states:

> Field url of type ItemUrl! must have a sub selection

If you go to docs (on the right on your screenshot), you'll find the URL object props:

[image]

What you need is to specify the subprop which in this case is also called `url`. In your query, instead of `url` use `url { url }`:

```
... on HeroBanner {
  products {
    targetItems {
      url {
        url
      }
    }
  }
}
```